# What do the numbers mean at the end of add_action('save_post')...?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, metabox, actions, save-post

I've seen on a few tutorials that there are numbers at the end of the call to save Custom Fields/Meta Boxes on the `save_post` hook. For example, in the [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action) it gives the following example:

```
<?php add_action( 'save_post', 'my_save_post', 10, 2 ); ?>
```

What do the **10** and **2** mean at the end?

I've tried talking to an "expert", but they've been of no help ;)

Comment: You yourself have linked to the codex entry that answers this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 10 is the priority (relative to other added actions) and the 2 is simply the number of arguments that my_save_post() will accept.

See [the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action).